# Issue with Warframe & Vulcan drivers on a GTX 560M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam, lutris

I have the latest drivers installed but it seems that [Vulcan support](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver) is not available for my GPU (GTX 560M).

Here's all the error messages I get when running Warframe on Lutris:

1. Just after opening Lutris

[image]

2. Lutris app: Works fine
   [image]
3. Error message on clicking Warframe
   [image]
4. 2nd error message before the game even runs

[image]

On first installing Warframe, the game launcher ran fine and download the whole game in its entirety but failed to run the game. After one restart this is the series of errors I get.

Should I try Steam Proton GE or is there no hope to run Warframe on a GTX 560M?

Answer (score 0):

you may choose on app configuration and tab "system option", primusrun for nvidia primus desktop, that s worked for me with gt560M